# How do I beat Donkey Kong at 100m?

Tags: donkey-kong-94

I made it to the top of the 100m area of Level 1, thinking it would work like the previous areas - get to the top, and Donkey Kong runs off with the girl again. Instead, he picked me up, tossed me around, and killed me!

How do I beat him?

Comment: Hey Ashley, which version of Donkey Kong are you playing? The classic arcade one?

Comment: see here... http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=RiHI2ZYxsBY#t=148s

Comment: @JohnoBoy The GameBoy release of the arcade version. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its the classic arcade version there are steel rivets you run over, once you get all if them go to the top and the building now collapses.